# Is it appropriate to merge guest user cart items with items in the cart when a user logs in

Tags: php, e-commerce

I am implementing an e-commerce website in core PHP. Currently, if a guest user adds some products to the cart and later logs in then all the items in his existing cart are replaced with the new items. I wanted to ask is it the best way or should I merge the guest user cart items in cookie to that of that with user's cart items which are stored in the database.

Comment: What does this mean, "all the items in his existing cart are replaced with the new items"?

Comment: If you do merge, you'd have to validate the stored cart(s) - they may contain items which are no longer available.

Comment: Consider posting this question in UX Stack Exchange instead: http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like this: when user added some cart items and then logs in, a prompt appears (if logged user old cart is not empty):

> This account had X older items in the cart, do you want to load these too ?
>
> (Product X, Product Y).

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends on your requirements.  If you want the user to, for example be able to shop, and then log in on the payment screen, then it would seem to make sense to allow this.

I would not say there is any hard and fast rule here.

Now certainly allowing adding of guest cart items into a logged in user's cart may present some more security issues that you need to address, but if you think it will be useful to the overall site operation or if you have been directed to implement in this fashion, there is no problem with doing so.